# really bad power consumption on mid-2013 MacBook Air

Tags: macos, battery, power-management

I'm getting a really bad power consumption on my mid-2013 MacBook Air 11" w/ OS X 10.9.4.  I think the issue is that I have too many tabs open in Safari and SeaMonkey, and they're all taking a lot of power.

It seems that even having all such tabs minimised still lets them suck out all the power out of my Mac.

Is there a way to improve power consumption?  Looks like I'm only getting some 2 or 3 hours (instead of 9) on a nearly brand new machine that has been unboxed just a couple of months ago in the summer of 2014, with the battery only having 36 cycles on.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about SeaMonkey, not an app I've seen, but in Safari, make sure Prefs  <kbd>Cmd</kbd>   <kbd>,</kbd>  > Advanced > Internet Plugins : 'Stop plug-ins to save power' is checked